# what is the difference between spark.read.parquet vs pyarrow.hdfs.connect().read_parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I have files in hdfs in parquet format, there are two options to read it:

- spark.read.parquet(hdfs_path)
- pyarrow.hdfs.connect().read_parquet(hdfs_path)

May i know what is the difference between this two, and which one is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code ,`spark.read.parquet() function`, is native to Apache Spark. It is a method defined in the `DatasourceReader` class in Apache Spark's source code. It is implmented in Scala

The second piece of code, `pyarrow.hdfs.connect().read_parquet(hdfs_path)`, also reads parquet files from hdfs, but is implemented in Apache Arrrow and is defined the PyArrow library in Python.

The First code snippet shall read your parquet data in a Spark Dataframe and you will have all the parallel processing capabilities available to you from the get go.

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean that the pyarrow one is not having all the parallel processing power? so recommend using spark.read?

Comment: Pyarrow assists in reading parquet files, butto process the data in parallel, you need to use a framework such as **Dask**